# Get a random row via EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm building an asp.net core webapp, and now I need to collect a random row from the database (sql) for posting in one of the views. Would very much appreciate any help I can get in doing and understanding this. Code, explanations, links to postings, enything is useful.

I don't fully understand how EF-asp.net core works, so that's what really makes it hard in searching for posts that are related to my problem.

Thank you in advance.

/Peter

Answer (score 5):

In EF (EF Core) you can simple use LINQ syntax (OrderBy method) in this way:

```
context.MyEntities.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using EF, I'll provide you with a LINQ-solution.

```
int total = context.YourEntities.Count();
Random r = new Random();
int offset = r.Next(0, total);

var result = context.YourEntities.Skip(offset).FirstOrDefault();
```

All this code does is get the total number of records, and generate a random number between [0, total). Note the boundary types: inclusive from the lower-end, exclusive from the upper-end.

You use this random number as an "offset", that is, how many records to skip (`.Skip(offset)`), and then retrieve the very first element of the remaining part of the sequence. If there are no records at all, `FirstOrDefault` returns `null`.

Comment: Thank you very much! A couple of follow up questions: 1) Does this work even with bigger databases and 2) If you're to put this snippet in a function in the repository, what type would that function have?

Comment: 1) Depends on DB vendor. With MSSQL, I am pretty sure this is efficient, since there are T-SQL constructs for pagination, however, with Oracle, for example, the last time I used it you had to mess around with  ROWNUM and other silly things just to get the nth record which required you to select the entire table first in a subquery (though I assume it could still utilize some optimizations but Oracle is not one of my beloved technologies and I am far from knowing it well). 2) How do you mean what type? What return type? Of course, the type of the entity that particular repository holds.

Comment: 2) Nevermind. I don't know where my brain went just there...Again, thank you for all help!